# What is the total number of combination

Tags: combinatorics

I am actually a programmer who is very bad in Maths. So, actually I am stuck in a question which goes like this:

You have given multiple boxes of candies and the number of candies each one of them will be given to you. Each candy has a number on it and every candy has a distinct number. You are also given a number **k** and  you have to find how many distinct subset of size **k** can be made.

For example, the if  **k is 3** and the candy boxes are = **1 ,2,1,1** . Then the answer will be  7.

Explanation - Lets suppose the candies in each box are numbered as **{1},{2,3},{4},{5}**

Then the possible combination of size 3 are :

{1,2,4}
{1,2,5}
{1,3,4}
{1,3,5}
{1,4,5}
{2,4,5}
{3,4,5}

See in the example, I can only select 1 candy from box 2, either it is 2 or 3.

So, I know choosing each candy from the box will be nC1 , But what I don't getting is how can I combine them to get the result

Comment: So you can’t select more than one candy from any box?

Comment: @TavishMusic Yes, we can not select more  than one candy from any box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polynomial coefficient method is widely used for combinatorics problems. The answer for this one is the coefficient of $x^{k}$ from:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\left(1+a_{i}x\right)}
$$

With $n$ denotes the number of bags and $a_{i}$ is the number of candies inside bag $i$.

In Your example, $(1+x)(1+2x)(1+x)(1+x)=2x^{4}+7x^{3}+9x^{2}+5x+1$. The coefficient of $x^{3}$ is $7$.

Detailed explanation: to obtain $x^{3}$ we need to choose from which bracket each of $x$ come from, this is analogous to choosing $3$ candies mean choosing from which bag we take it. For example, one of the $x^{3}$ comes from $(1+\bf{x}$$)(\bf{1}$$+2x)(1+\bf{x}$$)(1+\bf{x}$$)$ which corespond to taking candies from bag $1,3,4$. Bag $2$ has $2x$ instead of $x$ since we have $2$ candies in bag $2$

Comment: Can you explain a little, sorry but I am really bad at maths.

Comment: @Raddix hi there, i added some explanation with example. If You wish to ask more, feel free.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks for the help.